# Visual Studio Code terminal and G++

Tags: c++, powershell, visual-studio-code, g++

I'm using VS code as my IDE fr a small C++ project, and I'm using the terminal to compile it using G++ (I know I could set up a build environment but I find it easier for now).

```
g++ *.cpp -o main
```

Problem is, when I compile a bunch of files, and the compiler tell me that something is wrong, I go back to the editor, apply the changes, and then recompile, but the terminal shell (Powershell in my case), still "sees" the old file.

Only closing the terminal and reopening a new shell solves the issue.

This is very annoying, since I find VS code a great IDE.

Comment: Sounds like your `Makefile` has some issues.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, never touched it, how can I fix it?

Comment: If you want an actual answer I suggest you [edit] your question to provide the contents of the Makefile, and any other relevant files that your project uses for compiling.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I don't use a makefile, I just use g++ at command line

Comment: Then provide the exact command you use to compile, including any flags. And just to cover all bases, do you actually _save_ the file in your IDE so the changes are applied to disk before you recompile?